# Php md5 Passwords on C# Client

Tags: c#, php, passwords, md5, mybb

I'm trying to make a login system. All accounts on a Mybb forum system. I want the login to client using the mybb_users database. But passwords md5. And there is a colon by name: "salt". How can I encrypt the passwords on checking password?
This is my codes(If email and password is true)

```
 int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;

            }
if (count == 1) // IF Ok.
                {
                    userLabel.Text = myReader[0].ToString();
                    loginSuccessTimer1.Enabled = true;
                    LoginFormSuccessBG loginSuccess = new LoginFormSuccessBG();
                    loginSuccess.Show();
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your passwords are stored in a MyBB-database they will follow this form:

```
md5(password + md5(salt))
```

In other words first get the md5 hash of the salt, then add that to the password and then create the md5 hash of that. The resulting string is what will be stored in the MyBB-database.

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
string salt = // get salt from db
string password = // get password from user
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

// Create md5 hash of salt
byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(salt);
byte[] saltHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(salt);
string saltHash = System.BitConverter.ToString(saltHashBytes);

// Create your md5(password + md5(salt)) hash
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password + saltHash);
byte[] passwordHashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(salt);
string passwordHash = System.BitConverter.ToString(passwordHashBytes);
```

Comment: Wow, do they really not support a more save hash algorithm? This scheme is terribly unsafe, password cracker tools support it out of the box with a speed of 8 Giga hashes per second.

Comment: Had a quick search and it seems that they think it is [not a critical security issue](http://community.mybb.com/thread-170294.html). I wonder what they consider critical, for me this would be a reason to clearly stay away from the software. But anyway your answer is good.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong... But while md5 is not the best hashing algorithm, this implementation uses a salt and two md5-iterations. So the possibility of there being tables/and or a succesful reverse hash are not large.

Comment: The problem with MD5 are not existing rainbow-tables, a proper salt will prevent their usage. The problem is the incredible speed of todays GPUs. With a normal GPU you can brute-force about 8 Giga, with a 1000$ GPU you can calculate more than [100 Giga MD5 per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance). Testing a whole english dictionary will take only a fraction of a milllisecond! That is why one should use an algorithm with a cost factor like BCrypt, SCrypt or PBKDF2. BTW hashing the salt is absolute nonsense, you do it once and can use the result as the new salt.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. Slow algorithms with many iterations  sounds like the way to go :)

Comment: So, i was afraid :) And I've created a new colon for the launcher passwords and created a custom profile fields on mybb forum system. I'll use these hided profile fiels for logging into client. Thanks for all answers! :)